# What's considered undeniable proof in international affairs, and is undeniable proof of spying possible?

Tags: united-states, china, international

https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202302/1286118.shtml

> Although the US kept propagating the Chinese "spy balloon" narrative,
> it failed to provide proof to support its accusations even with the
> debris of the shot-down Chinese balloon having been collected and
> assessed.

China claims the U.S. didn't provide any proof, but the U.S. claims that it found evidence that it wasn't a weather balloon.

> The U.S. said that the balloon was capable of geolocating electronic
> communications and carried intelligence surveillance equipment
> inconsistent with that of a weather balloon.[10] It added that similar
> Chinese spy balloons have flown over more than 40 nations.[11][10]
> Analysts said that its flight path and structural characteristics were
> dissimilar from those of a typical weather balloon.[12][13][14]
> American officials later disclosed that they had been tracking the
> Chinese balloon since it was launched from Hainan. Its original
> destinations were likely Guam and Hawaii,[a] but prevailing winds blew
> it off course and across North America.[16]

Is it because the evidence suggest it wasn't a civilian balloon, but doesn't prove it, what kind of proof would be considered to be undeniable by a country like China?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSdVL2gh6ck

Another expert claimed they didn't have any proof.

https://nationalpost.com/opinion/was-the-spy-balloon-really-spying

> It is now well over a week since the Chinese balloon was shot down
> over the Atlantic coast **yet there is no word from the Americans about
> its payload.** Since the balloon sailed over Canada, and Ottawa
> presumably agreed with the Americans that it should not be shot down
> over its territory, the federal government ought to have technical
> experts at the FBI lab that is examining the balloon.
>
> **Expect the FBI to claim, as the Biden administration has repeatedly
> asserted, that the balloon had espionage capabilities;** the president
> and the Pentagon must not be contradicted by a U.S. agency. Similarly,
> expect China to repeatedly voice its claim that there is no verifiable
> evidence of a spy balloon.

Comment: I'm sorry who is the expert in the YouTube video, what is his field of expertise? [His Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Hammond_(historian)) introduces him as a historian but it spends more words on his relation with China and a university shooting than anything that would qualifying as an expert on spying / aviation / geopolitics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A sufficiently brazen country can deny anything. 70 years ago, under completely different circumstances, China denied that it was sending [regular army units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Volunteer_Army) to Korea and the Soviet Union insisted that it was not sending [air force units](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/196389/soviet-pilots-over-mig-alley/). A decade later, the US insisted that [U-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1960_U-2_incident#American_cover-up_and_exposure) were civilian aircraft in technical difficulties.

At some point, denying the undeniable will hurt the *international* reputation of a country more than it helps. But making the formal admission could have legal consequences, or it might filter into the domestic politics.

Comment: The irony there being that the USSR knew exactly what the U-2s were for quite some time, having had [spies on the ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selmer_Nilsen) next to the base in Norway (eventually found and convicted).

Comment: And Eisenhower also covered up the Soviets' involvement in Korea. https://edition.cnn.com/2023/01/20/asia/korean-war-fighter-pilot-soviet-shootdown-intl-hnk-ml/index.html

Comment: Isn't it the same as saying that hackers were sponsored by China when the only proof they have is that the hackers were based in China? I am trying to understand how solid their proof is.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSdVL2gh6ck

Comment: @Fizz This is kind of "Right for the wrong reasons" the Soviet Union was aware of the spy plane because pilot Francis Gary Powers did not detonate the plane on eject nor did he kill himself as he was instructed.  The USSR delibertly omitted Power's survival (and that he was likely talking) in thier initial report and let America commit to a cover story of a NASA weather plane pilot reporting oxygen problems and passing out while the plane was on autopilot... once America was in too deep, Kruschev revealed they had the pilot and the plane (and thus knew what instraments were onboard.).

Comment: @Sayaman, as I understand it China admitted that the balloon was theirs and claimed it was scientific, not military. That's different from hackers using a Chinese IP, which might be a VPN from North Korea, or Nigeria, or even the US ...

Comment: How do they know it was a spy balloon? The solar panels and radio sensors could have been used for another purpose than spying.

Comment: @Sayaman, if that was the case, one *might* expect them to tell the international scientific community before launch. Or at the very least, to tell the US air traffic control once it started to "drift out of control."

Comment: good point, but it still doesn't seem to prove absolutely it wasn't a civilian balloon.

Comment: @Sayaman, which returns full circle to my answer: it isn't about legal proof (in whose court of law?), it is about credibility in the eyes of the international community. Too many inconsistencies hurt the political standing of a country.

Comment: And Russia insists it is not at war with Ukraine.

Answer (score 0):

When you say X and then are demonstrably wrong - to the point when it's impossible to deny that you were wrong - then it becomes "undeniable proof".

Example: in 1960, the US flew a U2 reconnaissance plane over the USSR. The USSR shot it down, leading the US to assume that the plane had been destroyed and the pilot killed. They then claimed that the plane was a weather research aircraft and not a military spy plane, had encountered oxygen difficulties while flying over Turkey which rendered the pilot unconscious, and the autopilot had flown the plane into the USSR. They then did things like ground all U2s for oxygen checks, paint a U2 in NASA colours, etc to make the cover story seem more real.

The cover story imploded when the USSR produced the pilot of the plane, alive and well.

You can read more about the incident on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1960_U-2_incident).

Comment: Well, spies being caught and confessing is rather common. OTOH it's less clear what it took to abandon the cover of an unmanned program during the cold war, like the US' own spy balloon adventure of 1956 https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71081/when-was-the-official-cover-of-project-genetrix-abandoned-did-the-soviets-show

Comment: And the first US spy satellites were also covered by disinformation as to their true purpose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORONA_(satellite)#Discoverer